# SAS calculations in datastep

Tags: sas, dataset

I read a lot about the first. and last. function and basic calculations in SAS, though I want to circumvent the following problem in the datastep (if possible):

I need to flag each observation that exceeds the 25th percentile in each direction. I.e. I want to calculate outliers and give them either a 1 or 0 (outlier or not). The problem I have is that I want to do it for a group/class of observations in the dataset.

```
Group Value OutlierFlag
a    1     1
a    10    0
a    11    0
a    400   1
b    2     0
b    2     0
b    500   1
```

To complicate/advance: I need to add a time-grid which means I need to sum all observations each minute and write down the value onto a kind of grid (the current observations are not in specified time intervals). I already produced the grid (minute steps). But how can I sum up observations and include them into the grid datastep in each minute observations?
I am sorry if this is too blurry but maybe one of you knows how to do that or has an idea. I am very thankful!

Best!

EDIT:

Alright, I tested:

```
proc means data = MM.Data median P25 P75; 
class Security;
ods output Summary=mm.Data_median; 
var price spread; run; 

data mm.data; set mm.Data_median;
run;
```

That basically gives me the Proc Means Output. But I want the original dataet filled with the p25 and p75 variables. 
Then I tried:

```
proc sql; 
create table mm.newData as select *, sum(spread) as sumspread 
from mm.Data 
group by RIC; quit;
```

But it firstly groups it again and then there is no P25 function (I just entered sum for trial reasons).

Comment: Please post what you've tried. First/Last isn't appropriate for this question, however using BY groups most likely is required. Without a good data sample, expected output and what you've tried we're guessing on too many things.

Comment: Hi Reeza, thanks for the answer. Well I tried Proc SQL but apparently there is no P25 or similar function. Then I tried Proc Means with P25 and P75 but it collapses the data which I don't want. - Can I append the Proc means output to the original dataset and grab the values I need for calculations?

Comment: Post what you've tried in question please. If you have SAS 9.4 it may support quantile functions. Otherwise proc means is the common way to do this.

Comment: Just did it, sorry!

Comment: You'll have to merge the proc means output back with the original dataset.  It's not possible to calculate a percentile in a single pass through a dataset.

Comment: Alright thats exactly what I mean. How can I merge the Proc Means output back? When I do this, it just shows the statistics observations. But I want to duplicate the P25 and P75 with the key of each security so that I can calculate further (flag if a value is an outlier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add STACKODS & NWAY options to Proc means. This only calculates at
  highest level (ie only at group levels) and keeps data wide.
- Merge in using BY Group

  ```
  proc means data=sashelp.class nway stackods median p25 p75;
      class sex;
      var weight;
      ods output summary=stats;
  run;

  proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
      by sex;

  data want;
      merge class stats (keep=sex median p25 p75);
      by sex;
      flag_p75=ifn(weight>p75, 1, 0);
  run;
  ```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!! Works like a charm and NWAY and STACKODS are so useful